# Does resteasy support automatically mapping String/JSON MultipartFormDataInput to a object using jackson?

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson, resteasy

In my rest service I am trying to upload file with JSON object using multipart/form-data. I am using resteasy MultipartFormDataInput in my back end to handle the request and access file and JSON object

I can handle my file and JSON object as below;

```
 @POST
 @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
 public void uploadFile(MultipartFormDataInput input) throws IOException {
    Map<String, List<InputPart>> uploadForm = input.getFormDataMap();
    List<InputPart> fileInputParts = uploadForm.get("uploadedFile");
    List<InputPart> jsonInputParts = uploadForm.get("content");

    //convert the uploaded file to inputstream
    InputStream inputStream = fileInputParts.get(0).getBody(InputStream.class, null);
    byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);

    //Convert the uploaded JSON object
    GenericRestBean bean = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonInputParts .get(0).getBodyAsString(), GenericRestBean.class);
```

I am using jackson Object mapper to convert body string into JSON object. The problem in here is this mapping will ignore normal bean validation and I need to re implement it manually.

Does resteasy support automatically mapping String/JSON part to a object using jackson? If yes can anyone help me to get this object from MultipartFormDataInput object?

Answer (score 1):

By further reading I able to find a solution for my issue. We can unmarshall Input part using GenericType as below;

```
GenericRestBean bean = content.get(0).getBody(new GnericType<GenericReferenceRestBean>() {});
```

But I still have issue with bean validation. Since we put our bean validation inside the bean we have to put @Valid annotation wherever we need to validate that bean. But here how I can put that annotation? Please share if anyone have an idea.